# Do "a request to repeat the words" and "a task to construct a sentence" both qualify as "teacher's instructions"?

Tags: phrase-request

> She is always more than ready to **travel** - be it **a short trip** to some
>   town or **a long flight** by an airplane to another continent.

Here both "short trip" and "a long flight" qualify as "travel"

So, do "a request to repeat the words" and "an assignment to construct a whole sentence" also qualify as "teacher's instructions" in the following example?:

> She is very attentive and is more than ready to follow upon her teacher's **instructions** – be it merely **a request to repeat words** aloud after the teacher or **an assignment to construct** a whole sentence by herself.

If not, then what better term (word or a phrase) would encompass both? "Teacher's commands"?

Comment: "whole flight" is odd.  Do you mean "long flight"?

Comment: And you might  change *task* to *assignment*. To my ear, *assignment* is like a *request* in that it can refer to the act of asking or telling someone what you would like or would require them to do, whereas the noun *task* does not refer to the act of asking or telling; it refers rather  to *that which* you ask someone to do or tell them to do.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Thank you. just changed that, too. A small side question: Why is "be it an assignment  to construct **a whole** sentence" is okay, but "be it **a whole** flight" is odd?

Comment: Because a sentence is made of parts, phrases and clauses, whereas a flight is a unity, unless it is a flight of sample beers or a flight of stairs.  What idea do you mean to convey with the word **whole** there with "flight"?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - "What idea do you mean to convey with the word whole there with "flight"?" - The idea was to contrast a long flight and a short trip. Like "a flight" is an absolutely another "class" of a travel, a whole other story" (not sure if it's correct to say so in English)

Comment: You could say "be it a short trip or a *transcontinental* flight"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "request", strictly speaking, is not really an "instruction", so if you're looking for a generic phrase that would satisfy someone who might quibble there:

> She is very attentive and always ready to **heed** her teacher's **words**...